# React Checkbox onCheck get key value

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, event-handling, onchange, semantic-ui

I am currently working on a website I am building with React, and I am not able to get the Checkbox key value from the onChange event. This is what my code looks like:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log('it works');
    console.log(e.target.key);
}
```

And my Checkbox code:

```
<Table.Cell><Checkbox key={singleNews.key} name="myCheckBox1" onChange={this.handleChange}/></Table.Cell>
```

It simply prints out 'it works', and 'undefined'. I have also used 'this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this) in my constructor. Could anyone please help me find out what the error might be? For the record; I am currently using the Semantic UI React framework - could this be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would do console.log(e.target.tagname) and check to see if the target is the checkbox or the table cell, then go from there

Comment: What is Checkbox? is it some self rolled component or from a library?

Comment: @megamit Yes, checkbox is a self rolled component posing as a regular 'styled checkbox'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all the key property in react is a special prop that should not be [accessed by your app and treated as internal to react](https://reactjs.org/blog/2014/10/16/react-v0.12-rc1.html#breaking-change-key-and-ref-removed-from-thisprops)

If you are not trying to use the key for anything and instead just trying to get the updated data from [this issue thread](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/638) it should be possible to access the value in your event handler like this:

```
handleChange = (e, data) => {
    console.log('it works');
    console.log(data.value);
}
```

If you want to pass data into your event handler based on data it received when runnning then what you can do is change your Checkbox code to this:

```
<Table.Cell>
    <Checkbox name="myCheckBox1" onChange={(e, data) => this.handleChange(singleNews.key, data.value)}/>
</Table.Cell>
```

And your change handler to this

```
handleChange = (key, value) => {
    console.log('here\'s the key', key);
    console.log('and the value', value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not know this. Saved me a lot of time.

Comment: So in other words, I should just be using the name for setting an unique id for my website? It's being used to mark specific messages, and then change them according to the ID.

Comment: What you can do is bind the value you want your change handler to receive at render time. i will update my answer

Comment: I see. Do you happen to know how I would make the checkbox check unique? What I mean by that is; it's only possible to tick only one specific, and not multiple.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [docs of `semantic-ui-react`](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/checkbox#checkbox-example-checkbox) (this is the library you are using according to the tags right?) you get 2 parameters: `event` and `data`.

The `data` is:

> All props and proposed checked/indeterminate state.

So your code should be something like:

```
handleChange = (e, data) => {
    console.log('it works');
    console.log(data); // the data / props that passed to the component
}
```

Note that `key` is reserved for `react` and won't pass back to the handler.
You can use any other `prop` though.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was not aware of the data parameter. Saved me a lot of time.

Comment: You can pass whatever prop you want and read it. For example `myId`

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks for telling me this, learning something new every single day!